# OOP design - when to have a common base class [Flaw design?]

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, class-design

I have a simplified design as the following (basically a bunch of handlers to handle 2 different types of request: EventRequest and SpeechRequest). Below is the pseudocode:

```
class SpeechRequest {sessionId: String; slot: String}
class EventRequest {sessionId: String; event: String}

class SpeechRequestHandler; 
class EventRequestHandler;

class SpeechRequestHandler[A/B/C] extends SpeechRequestHandler {
    - handle(request: SpeechRequest) {      
        doSt(request.slot)
    }
}

class EventRequestHandler[A/B/C] extends EventRequestHandler {
    - handle(request: EventRequest) {       
        doSt(request.event)     
    }   
}
```

There is 2 different dispatchers to find appropriate handlers for each types of requests and forward them to handlers to handle:

```
class SpeechDispatcher {
    - handle(request: SpeechRequest) {
        handler: SpeechRequestHandler = findHandlerToHandle(request);
        handler.handle(request);
    }
}

class EventDispatcher {
    - handle(request: EventRequest) {
        handler: EventRequestHandler = findHandlerToHandle(request);
        handler.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Now, i want to refactor and create a base/common classes. Naturally, I came up with this:

```
class Request {sessionId: String}
class SpeechRequest extends Request {slot: String}
class EventRequest extends Request {event: String}

class RequestHandler {
    - canHandleRequest(Request): bool
    - handle(Request)
}

class SpeechRequestHandler extends RequestHandler {
    - canHandleRequest(request: Request): bool = request instanceof SpeechRequest
}

class EventRequestHandler extends RequestHandler {
    - canHandleRequest(request: Request): bool = request instanceof EventRequest
}

class SpeechRequestHandler[A/B/C] extends SpeechRequestHandler {
    - handle(Request: request) {
        //need to cast to specific type to extract a certain fields to do some operation
        //!! I feel something is not right because of that
        speechRequest:SpeechRequest = (SpeechRequest)request;
        doSt(speechRequest.slot)

        //other operation can work with base Request object; so it's OK
    }
}

class EventRequestHandler[A/B/C] extends EventRequestHandler {
    - handle(Request: request) {
        eventRequest:EventRequest = (EventRequest)request;
        doSt(eventRequest.event)

        //other operation can work with base Request object; so it's OK
    }   
}
```

The fact that for all SpeechRequestHandler[A/B/C]:handle functions, I now need to cast the Request object to (SpeechRequest) object specifically: speechRequest:SpeechRequest = (SpeechRequest)request;

I feel that there is flaw in my design. If every SpeechRequestHandler I need to cast the object to (SpeechRequest) so that I can do something with those info, does it means that it doesn't make sense to refactor a base class in this case ?

Please could you suggest a better way or a design pattern to handle this cleanly.

Thank you.

Comment: You may want to tag the correct language.

Comment: @Tom: my original code is in java but the above (mixed with some scala style) makes the code shorter to represent here.

Comment: Could you use generics defined on `RequestHandler` to constrain the type of the expected event on the implementations?

Comment: @MadProgramer: No, I don't want to use generic because my handler is initialized by spring bean, and it doesn't work very well with generics. In addition, it will add additional complexity. I'm just wondering is this something normal to cast the class into specific type as in the above ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay type-safe, you can do this sort of thing with double dispatch.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

It looks like you want something like this:

```
interface HandlerSet{
    SpeechHandler getSpeechHandler(Request request);
    EventHandler getEventHandler(Request request);
}

abstract Request {
    ... common stuff ...
    abstract handleWith(HandlerSet handlers);
}
class SpeechRequest extends Request {
    sessionId: String; slot: String
    handleWith(HandlerSet handlers) {
        return handlers.getSpeechHandler(this).handle(this);
    }
}
class EventRequest extends Request {
    sessionId: String; event: String
    handleWith(HandlerSet handlers) {
        return handlers.getEventHandler(this).handle(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have introduced a method that can be invoked with every type of `Request`, but concrete handlers for the request must know the concrete type.

Something like this

```
 public void handleRequest(Request request){
      // Find the correct handler
      for(RequestHandler requestHandler : requestHandlers){
           if(requestHandler.canHandle(request)){
               // Opps, the handler needs the concrete type
               requestHandler.handle(request);
           }
      }
 }
```

At runtime the only object that has enough information to know which handler can handle it is the `Request`. Thus you must ask the request to choose a specific target method to call.

This is called the [`visitor pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
public interface Request {
    public void accept(RequestVisitor requestVisitor);
}

public interface RequestVisitor {
    public void visit(SpeechRequest speechRequest);
    public void visit(EventRequest eventRequest);
}
```

A `Request` implementation can now decide which callback of the `RequestVisitor` must be invoked:

```
public class SpeechRequest implements Request {
    public void accept(RequestVisitor requestVisitor) {
        requestVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public class EventRequest implements Request {
    public void accept(RequestVisitor requestVisitor) {
        requestVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

and the concrete handler can then use the concrete request object

```
public class SpeechRequestHandler {
    public void handle(SpeechRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

public class EventRequestHandler {
    public void handle(EventRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

From a client's perspective the visitor might be used like this:

```
SpeechRequestHandler speechRequestHandler = new SpeechRequestHandler();
EventRequestHandler eventRequestHandler = new EventRequestHandler();

RequestVisitor requestVisitor = new RequestVisitor() {

    @Override
    public void visit(EventRequest eventRequest) {
        eventRequestHandler.handle(eventRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(SpeechRequest speechRequest) {
        speechRequestHandler.handle(speechRequest);
    }
};

Request request1 = new SpeechRequest();
Request request2 = new EventRequest();

request1.accept(requestVisitor);
request2.accept(requestVisitor);
```

But using the visitor pattern is often (but not always) a hint for that you tried to make an interface too abstract. That's why you've lost the type information that you have to re-create later. Maybe you will find a better design.